# Integral relate to Hahn polynomial

Tags: calculus

I try to calculate te following integral
$$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{e^{x z} \left(\text{sech}^2\right(\pi  x) ) \Gamma \left(n+\frac{i x}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2 \Gamma \left(\frac{i x}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)} \, dx $$
I try to use Nassalla-Raman integral
[image]
and Mellin convolution but I get no result.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are the conditions on $z$ and $n$? For nice $z$ and $n$, substituting $x = -2 i t$ and reducing all factors to $\Gamma(a_k \pm t)$ gives the definition of the Meijer G-function.

Comment: Thanks @Maxim , good idea ,This type of orthogonal polynomials those of hanh and those of wilsom used to accelerate representations of functions, use many degrees of freedom and are not very fast like the classic ones making them few useful, but only theoretical and diicult to calculate